# Split CSV by number of rows and keep headers

Tags: csv, awk

I have this command to split csv by number of rows, `line=` part.
But this cmd does not keep headers from original file and I need to have the headers there. Can you please help me? I found that I need to keep headers separately and then somehow add the n of rows.

It loads `output.csv` file and splits it every 33 rows in a result file which is called `output<number>.csv` with numbers before the extension and starting from 1.

```
awk -v N=1 -v pre="output" -v suf=".csv" -v line=33 'NR%line==1{x=pre N suf ;N++} {print > x}' output.csv
```

How can I keep the headers and keep my functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that output.csv is

```
header
1a
2a
3a
1b
2b
3b
1c
2c
3c
```

Just fixing a little bit your code :

```
awk -v pre="output" -v suf=".csv" -v line=3 '
NR == 1 {
    header = $0
    next
}
NR % line == 2 {
    close(x)
    N++
    x = pre N suf
    print header > x
}
{
    print > x
}
' output.csv
```

Creates 3 files :

output1.csv

```
header
1a
2a
3a
```

output2.csv

```
header
1b
2b
3b
```

output3.csv

```
header
1c
2c
3c
```

Don't forget to [close](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html) if you write many files.

Comment: @EdMorton I did ask myself the question! I was lazy and didn't read the link I provided entirely `close() silently does nothing if given an argument that does not represent a file, pipe, or coprocess that was opened with a redirection.` . Thank you :)